# Creating Welds During Simulation

Tags: drake

Is there any way to create a weld joint during a simulation in Drake? For context, I am trying to get a robot to assemble furniture, and whenever it attaches two pieces of furniture (ie. a chair leg with its base), I want to weld them together.

I have attempted using **LinearBushingRollPitchYaw**, with large damping and spring constant values, but I was either not getting "welds" or there would be a segfault.

I have also thought about stopping the simulation, doing the weld, and restarting the simulation, but I was not sure if this was practical.

Is something like this possible in Drake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some related information:

- https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/14200
- https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/15137
- https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13291